# Word or phrase for making something seem better by comparison

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

What is a word or phrase that expresses the idea of purposely making something seem better by comparison? For example, lemon Starburst was created to make the cherry flavor seem that much tastier.

Comment: Is there something about *by comparison* that you don't like, or are you just looking for alternatives?

Comment: The latter. I asked the question because I keep on thinking there is a more specific term that I just can't remember.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name for something that is used to make something else look different by comparison is a *foil*:

> **foil**, noun. Anything that serves by contrast of colour or quality to adorn another thing or set it off to advantage.

The presence of a foil induces a cognitive bias known as a [*contrast effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_effect).

I'm not aware of any terms that mean *to create a foil* or *to induce a contrast effect*.

Answer (score 1):

> *Watson is a perfect **foil** for Holmes because his relative obtuseness makes Holmes's deductions seem more brilliant.*

[Britannica Online]

(emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Differentiated.

The lemon starburt differentiated cherry from other flavors.

Answer (score 0):

You can say something like: "The lemon Starburt was created to make cherry flavor seem tastier by comparison."