# What is a word to describe how something bad looks good because it is being contrasted with something worse?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, literary-techniques

I was wondering if there was any word or terminology for any such literary device that uses this effect.

Comment: Damning with faint praise?

Comment: Something being the lesser of two evils?

Comment: backhanded compliment?

Comment: You might say something like "Even is really dumb. Mark isn't very smart, but he's a genius by comparison." See 'better by comparison': http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65176/word-or-phrase-for-making-something-seem-better-by-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the literary device term you're looking for is [*creating a foil*](http://literary-devices.com/frontpage?page=3) where a foil is another character in a story who contrasts with the main character, usually to highlight one of their attributes.

[*Juxtaposition*](http://literary-devices.com/frontpage?page=4) is a literary device wherein the author places a person (etc) parallel to another in order to highlight the contrast between the two and compare them.

Non-literary comparisons would be setting up a false equivalency, *rigging the deck*, or [*stacking the deck*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stack): to manipulate events, information, etc., in order to achieve an advantage or desired result.